# How to count the values in a hive partitined table

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a partitioned table with 2 columns `(country,status)` now I want to count the number of `SUCCESS` and `ERROR` times in `status` column.
How do I sort this problem?

Comment: Please add code so someone could help you this is not the way to ask questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use case statements with aggregation:

```
select country,
       sum(case when status='SUCCESS' then 1 end) cnt_SUCCESS,
       sum(case when status='ERROR'   then 1 end) cnt_ERROR
  from tablename
group by country;
```

Remove `group by country` and `country` column if you need total counts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use where condition to get the results

Select count(status) from .. where status = 'SUCCESS';
UNION
Select count(status) from .. where status = 'ERROR';